# Match any character except line break (mysql regex)

Tags: mysql, regex

I would like to use a regex using regexp instruction in a mysql query.
The regex contains a rule any character except line break.

`SELECT * FROM column regexp 'EXP1.*=*.*EXP2'`

But mysql seams to treat .* as any character including line break

Any ideas how to change the regex to match any character except line break

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Depending on your line ending style, you could either use `[^\n]*` to match anything other than line feeds, or `[^\n\r]*` to match anything other than line feeds and carriage returns.

Comment: Should be [^\r\n]*

Comment: @BeneTleilax: Actually, brackets indicate a character class.  The order does not matter, MySQL POD: "matches all characters belonging to that class", https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html